# Vertical align div in XHTML 1.1 for EPUB?

Tags: css, xhtml, webkit, epub, ibooks

I have been Googling this and find many entries on it, most of which use table-cell like this:

http://www.vdotmedia.com/blog/vertically-center-content-with-css/

They work fine, but why I change the DOCTYPE to XHTML1.1, which I need for an EPUB page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

It no longer works. Am I out of luck? I have blocks of text that vary in length that I would like to vertically center on a page in an epub reader such as iBooks (which are based on WebKit -- I do not need to worry about other browsers).

Comment: Are you aware XHTML 1.1 is for XML only applications? And why are you changing the doctype at all? That should be the first thing you put down and NEVER change it.

Comment: Yes, I know.  It was always XHTML1.1 from the way it is exported from InDesign.  When adding the CSS did not work in my file but did work in the sample on that web site, I suspected the DOCTYPE so took the example file and changed it to match my document, thereby confirming that's why it did not work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's another trick you can try.

If you have this structure:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="text">
    Some text you need aligned vertically
    </div>
</div>
```

On the CSS you'd have:

```
.container {
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
}

.text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
```

You can give that a go if you'd like. Change the height to whatever you need it to be of course.

Comment: Thanks.  Here's the thing, though: I'd rather not have to specify a height, so it would center on all the different size screens it might be seen on.

Comment: That's a tough one. I struggle with this myself sometimes. I always revert back to `display: table-cell` method. It seems to be the only way. I've yet to find a better method. You could of course replace your divs with a table. Table cells are vertically centered by default. I know you're supposed to stay away from tables, but if it works...

Comment: Yes, except it would seem table cell does not work right (or at all) in XHTML1.1

Comment: It only works, it seems, if you specify a numerical height for the table: http://jsfiddle.net/smlombardi/LnD3b/  In some of the example I've seen, they use min-height but it's not working for me.

Comment: You don't even need the container, but you DO need an explicit height, which is annoying: http://jsfiddle.net/smlombardi/LnD3b/11/

Comment: I meant explicitly using a `<table>`

Comment: Yes, I might have to do that.  Thanks.

Comment: The reason you need the containing `div` in this example is so that it's 50% from the top of the container and not from the top of the entire page.

Answer (score 2):

Only using a table with height:100% appears to work on the nook.

I tried

```
.container{display:table;height:100%;}
.content{display:table-cell; height:100%; vertical-align:middle;}
```

This doesn't work in XHTML 1.0 and XHTML 1.1 because html and body also need to be set to 100%

```
html{height:100%}
body{height:100%}
.container{display:table;height:100%;}
.content{display:table-cell; height:100%; vertical-align:middle;}
```

This works in Chrome, so I'm assuming it will work in all webkit browsers ( including the iPad reader. It's based off of webkit, right?) But it didn't work on the nook. This is what did the trick for me.

```
html{height:100%}
body{height:100%}
table { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
tr {width:100%; height:100%; vertical-align:middle;}
td {width:100%; height:100%; vertical-align:middle;}
h1#Title{font-size:6em;text-align: center; font-family:Logan; margin:0em;}
```

There may be some extra rules, but I don't have a very good development environment (Sigil -> Chrome -> Nook).

Answer (score 0):

Testing my response more, I realized it was premature... Can you just always put your div in the center of the screen with this:

```
.text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fAfX4/1/

Comment: That works with one line of txt, but not a paragraph: http://jsfiddle.net/Fcppr/1/ I mean, it works, but it does not look centered any longer.